# Issue with bcrypt.compare()

Tags: javascript, node.js, bcrypt

This method always returns undefined. It should return true or false. But it doesn't. Could someone help me sort it out?

```
connection.query('SELECT newpwd FROM userinfo WHERE username = ? ', param.username, function(err, hash, fields) {
   console.log("Db loaded hash :" + hash);
   if (err) return callback(err);
   else if (!hash.length) {
      return callback(err);
   } else {
      bcrypt.compare("abcdef", hash, function(err, result) {
         console.log(param.password);
         console.log(result);
         if (result == true) {
            console.log(param.password);
            console.log("Login hash :" + hash);
            return callback(null, "valid_user");
         } else return callback(null, "invalid_user");
      });
   }
});
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that "result" is undefined ?

Comment: Where is the `callback` defined ?

Comment: And who returns what ?

Comment: Same problem, wonder if it comes from storing the hash inside an SQL database